# Scaling divs inside row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scaling, css-transforms

I want to scale **divs .card-cell** which are inside **div .row**, but I've got additional padding/margin? around them.

```css
 .row .card-cell{
  zoom:0.53;
  -moz-transform:scale(0.53);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.53);
 }


.redBackground {
 background: #E32 !important;
}

.card {
     margin: 0.3em;
 width: 73px;
 height: 98px;
 float: left;
}

.no-padding{
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row ">
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="as-kier">
              1
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="dwa-kier">
              2
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="trzy-kier">
              3
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="cztery-kier">
              4
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="piec-kier">
              5
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="szesc-kier">
              6
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="siedem-kier">
              7
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="osiem-kier">
              8
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="dziewiec-kier">
              9
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="dziesiec-kier">
              10
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="walet-kier">
              walet
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 card-cell no-padding">
   <div class="no-padding card redBackground" id="dama-kier">
              dama
   </div>
  </div>
<!-- here is more divs with .col-xs-1 -->
 </div>
</div>
```

How to scale inside divs without this additional space around them?

---

Dev image with background and margins(?) around scaled divs:
[image: dev image of margins(?) around scaled divs]

Comment: `And why .row and .col-sx-1 are not displaying properly here in this stackoverflow's snippet` Because it's supposed to be `col-xs-1`(as in extra small)

Comment: Two things are unclear in your snippet. First you use a class 'no-padding' that isn't defined anywhere, and second you want them to scale but you're specifying a static width and height of the card divs?

Comment: I added .no-padding to css. I have specified width and height because I'm using for each .card id for example: 
**#as-kier { background: url(../img/windows-playing-cards.png) 0px -98px no-repeat; }**